# Как после сохранения данных в форме вернуть на главную страницу

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, form

У меня на главной странице есть список книг и есть кнопка для добавления новой книги ,по нажатию кнопки я перехожу на новую страницу и начинаю заполнять поля для создания книги .Я хочу чтобы по нажатию на кнопку сохранить меня возвращало обратно к списку моих книг

Если делаю так

```
 <td><input type="submit" value="Add Book" formaction="/Home/AdminForm" /></td>
```

то меня перекидывает на страницу со списком ,но книгу не сохранят .
Подскажите что нужно использовать

Если мало информации для понимая сути вопроса ,пишите - я добавлю инфу

Comment: В методе  сохранения, после сохранения делайте перенаправление на нужную страницу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `Action`, где сохраняете книгу, возвращайте `RedirectToAction()`, в котором укажите ссылку на `Action` контроллера, который возвращает `View` с вашими книгами.